# static adapter not working with nginx and refreshing pages

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, sveltekit

This is my config:

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';
import path from 'path';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: preprocess(),

    kit: {
        // hydrate the <div id="svelte"> element in src/app.html
        target: '#svelte',
        adapter: adapter({
            // default options are shown
            pages: 'build',
            assets: 'build',
            fallback: null
        }),
        vite: {
            resolve: {
                alias: {
                    $components: path.resolve('./src/components'),
                    $stores: path.resolve('./src/stores'),
                    $api: path.resolve('./src/api')
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

export default config;
```

however if I refresh any page in browser I get a 404....

index works, but nothing else if I refresh page.

Comment: Since you're mentioning nginx, I'm assuming you're encountering this issue in production? What were your build & deploy steps, and what does your nginx config look like for this app?

Comment: so it looks like a 404 during build will cause static routing to not work in production. Not sure if that's a bug.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue on an Apache server (DreamHost).

Comment: Yes. I added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up nginx docs for “try_files”.

Basically if the file doesn’t exist it redirects to index.html which will allow the client side router to handle refreshes

`try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;`

Comment: You should mentioned what you listed _after_ the word `try_files`. Here's what I ended up using that seemed to work: `try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html /index.html;` The /index.html at the end needs to match the `fallback: 'index.html'` part of your adapter-static config. Otherwise going directly to a route that doesn't have a matching file at that path -- such as any route with a dynamic param like `[id]` -- will result in a 404.

Comment: updated answer.

Comment: not having luck with similar setup & static build; setting the nginx try_files last part of string to `/index.html` and Sveltekit fallback 
 to `index.html` will redirect my dynamic routes yes to the Svelte src/routes/index.svelte but the client side router does not invoke so the page does not change (it should re-render with the correct dynamic route template).

Comment: I've given up on svelte and gone back to native ssr with mojolicious

Comment: this settings worked for me:

  location /my-site {
    default_type "text/html";
    alias /path;
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html /index.html;
  }`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: `try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html /index.html;`

Comment: Can you explain why this works?